# Access to an undefined property phpstan laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, phpstan

I´m trying to solve problems in my proyect. I have this message:

```
Access to an undefined property                                           
         Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::$bloqueante.                          
          Learn more:                                                            
            https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-access-to-undefined-property
```

in my model y have:

```
/**
 * App\Models\Validacion
 *
 * @property bool $bloqueante
```

and in my command class, that it´s where i´m calling to my model:

i try with

```
/**
 * @mixin $bloqueante
```

and `* @property bool $bloqueante`

but always returned this error. i´m reading how i can to ignore it, but i think tha it´s not better solution, if i can solve it, i prefer solve this message.

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Larastan? It’s a PHPStan extension focused on understanding Laravel well.

Try it and if it still doesn’t work, open an issue on Larastan’s GitHub, they’ll look into it.

Comment: yes it´s larastan i show his posts, buts not run solutions